# In pandas, how to insert one row of a dataframe into another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, insert, append

*I figured this out, so I am posting here.*

I want to insert one row of a DataFrame into another.

Let's say our first DataFrame is `df1`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]])
```

Now if there is another DataFrame, defined as:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
```

How to insert some specific rows of `df1` into `df2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, if you want to insert the 2nd and 3rd row of `df1` into `df2`:

```
df2 = df2.append(pd.Series(df1.iloc[2]))
df2 = df2.append(pd.Series(df1.iloc[3]))
```

If you want the values as **`int`**:

```
df2 = df2.astype(int)
```